# Django Form template not getting authenicated user name as post author

Tags: django

I am building a Django blog but created a template to post once a user signed. and the template working fine except an issue and that is, the post template show multiple author name, in this case, an authenticated user can post using any other user name.

**THe views.py below**

```
def create(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = CreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        redirect('user_login')
```

**And this Form.py file  below**

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'author',
            'title',
            'body',
            'image',
            'category'
        ]
```

I need only authenticated user name will be author name.

Can anyone please fix me this issue?

Comment: How do you authenticate the user.Are you using the session for storing the logged in user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `user=request.user` after `instance = form.save(commit=False)`